# XNA - how to prevent a sound from looping

Tags: xna, c#, sound, sound-effects

So in XNA I have this code:
Variables:

```
SoundEffect optionSelected;
```

In the `LoadContent()` method:

```
optionSelected = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("gameSounds\\selectOption");
```

In the `Update()` method:

```
optionSelected.Play();
```

So when it comes time for the sound to play it never stops looping. I want to hear it only once. How to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this question: [Game loop, how to check for conditions once, do something, then not do it again](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46756/game-loop-how-to-check-for-conditions-once-do-something-then-not-do-it-again)

Comment: This question is C++ related, I need c# xna help.

Comment: The logic is the same for either language. The first answer is somewhat specific to C++, but the other answers work just as well for C#.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are calling Play() every time the update loop runs it will play each time the game updates. However ignoring that to stop it looping you'd do

```
optionSelected = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("gameSounds\\selectOption");
optionSelected.IsLooped=false;
```

Hope that helps

EDIT: From the comment thread the solution would be to add a keypress event listener and call Play() when the desired key is pressed.

Comment: Uh... `IsLooped` is a member of `SoundEffectInstance` and **not** `SoundEffect`. The `Play` method on the latter is just a convenience method for fire-and-forget sounds which, naturally, don't support looping.

Comment: Yep this did not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How are you calling it from your update loop? you might want it after an if statement such as if(isOptionClicked==true) {optionSelected.Play(); isOptionClicked=false;}. Or stick it somewhere else

Comment: OK, I used a bool but now when it comes time for the sound to play, well it doesn't play. Reply would be really nice!

Comment: You have to set the boolean to true at some point. Are you sure you want the sound in the update loop. If this is for an option being selected then I'm assuming a button is clicked or something of that ilk. If so you could add an event handler to whatever is triggering the sound so when it's clicked it plays instead of keeping it in the update loop

Comment: It should play after a specific key was pressed.

Comment: then a keypress event which checks which key was pressed and plays the sound

Comment: Oh I'm so dumb! I've done this before when I used sounds, since I'm new to xna I can't quite remember everything. The problem was that I used to play the sound by using a bool but a keypress event should not fail me.

Comment: In that case I'll add it to my answer and if it works could you mark it as answered :)