# Creating a single GUI Text with Fade-In

Tags: c#, unity

I have this line of code

```
void Update () {

    float alVal = 0.0f; 
    float damping = 1f;
    alVal += damping * Time.time;
    GameObject text2 = new GameObject();

    text2.AddComponent (typeof(GUIText));
    text2.guiText.color = new Color (1f,1f,1f);
    text2.guiText.name = "name";
    text2.guiText.text = "YOLOMF";          
    text2.guiText.pixelOffset = new Vector2 (100, 100);

    text2.guiText.color = new Color(1f,1f,1f,alVal);

    Debug.Log (alVal);

}
```

I want to create a SINGLE TEXT, but I guess the Update() function keeps on making more.

I need that SINGLE TEXT to do an animation of Fade-In that's why it is in Update()

Comment: I guess you'd create the `GUIText` outside of `Update` then, so it only gets created once, then animate it inside `Update`? Or [set and check a flag to make sure it happens only once](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46756/game-loop-how-to-check-for-conditions-once-do-something-then-not-do-it-again)? This sounds like it's more about programming and not really about game development.

Comment: It's not programming really, I Just want to create a GUI Text using a code, but when I declare it outside the update, Update() function can't use it so that's why I placed the declaration inside the Update(). I cannot use flag because flag stops at 1 frame, but the Fade-In happens in a lot of frames.

Comment: You definitely should be able to use an object declared outside of a method inside a method. That seems like the root problem. I recommend making a minimal example of what you're trying and asking on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), who are a programming-focused site.

Comment: I would do your recommendation. If I may ask sir, would you make a code block wherein you can create a single `GUIText` in C and do a fade-in/fade-out? I think that would help a lot and might also solve my current problem. Thank you sir @Anko.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to go into more detail right now, but I hope you figure it out! Friendly tip: To get the best answers, it's best to [just concentrate on describing the problem, rather than the problem with a solution to that problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

This is a rough translation of the code you've provided into something that does not spawn a new GameObject on every frame.

```
private GUIText textObject;

void Start ()
{
    // Initialize the text when the behavior is "started"
    GameObject text2 = new GameObject();
    textObject = text2.AddComponent<GUIText>();
    textObject.color = new Color (1f,1f,1f);
    textObject.name = "name";
    textObject.text = "YOLOMF";     
    textObject.pixelOffset = new Vector2 (100, 100);
}

void Update () 
{
    // Fade a bit every frame ...
    float alVal = 0.0f; 
    float damping = 1f;
    alVal += damping * Time.time;
    textObject.color = new Color(1f,1f,1f,alVal);

    // TODO: Re-architect this to clean itself up.
}
```

There's several ways to improve the architecture of this but the "best" way completely depends on other architecture not defined here. This will have the effect you're looking for but I'd recommend you alter it to clean up after itself.